# Populating a list box with text AND value, ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I am wanting to know if there is a way to populate a list box with both text and value. The text bit is easy, but I want a value so I can have a user select something in it then press a button which gets the chosen value and uses an SQL query to do the rest.

My code so far for populating the text is:

```
listAllLessons.Items.Add(detail);
```

It runs in a loop and is populated from a database.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Web Forms:

HTML Side:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" 
                    runat="server" />
  <br />
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" 
              runat="server" 
              OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" 
              Text="Click Me" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    //Generate 20 items
    foreach(var count in Enumerable.Range(1, 20))
    {
      var newItem = new ListItem();

      newItem.Value = count.ToString();
      newItem.Text = "Item " + count.ToString();

      ddlList.Items.Add(newItem);
    }
  }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Gets the selected value
  var selectedValue = ddlList.SelectedValue;

  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried concatenating the items just like this:

```
    while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString() + "\t" + reader[1].ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that isn't quite what I needed, as I needed a ListBox item with both a text and value property, not just adjusting how it is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  ListItem li = new ListItem(Convert.ToString(reader["test"]), Convert.ToString(reader["value"]));
  ListBox1.Items.Add(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
dt = db.GetAllEmployeeForManagement();
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ListItem li = new ListItem(Convert.ToString(item["Name"]), Convert.ToString(item["EmployeeID"]));


                    if (!ListBox1.Items.Equals(li.Text))
                    {
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(li);
                    }
                }
```

where dt is actually a ref name of Datasource so.. it is quite simple!